# Puzzle: $(\Box @)+(\Box @) = (\Box\bigstar\Box$)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, puzzle

> Some ETs follow a positional number system, with the same base as the number of fingers on their hand. The following inscription is all the evidence we have: $$(\Box @)+(\Box @) = \Box\bigstar\Box $$ Find the number of fingers.

Attempt: $(xy)_b + (xy)_b = (xzx)_b$ Can be written as $2y+2bx=x+bz+b^2 x$ so I need to solve for $b$ the equation $b^2x+bz-2bx+x-y=0$ with $b\geq 2$ and $0\leq x,y,z<b $.

Comment: Regarding Source, M Gardner's mathematical games was mentioned in the book, but I havent been able to locate it. Please post an online link if you know it.

Comment: my interpretation of $(\Box @)+(\Box @) = (\Box\bigstar\Box)$ is $(xy)_b+(xy)_b=(xzx)_b$ and therefore $(bx+y)+(bx+y)=b^2x+zb+x$, which can be transformed into $2y+2xb=(b^2+1)x+bz$

Comment: Hint: When adding two double 'digit' integers together, the maximum carry you can get to the third position is equal to ...

Comment: @miracle173 made the correction

Comment: @Jyrki ..... 1?

Comment: Hmm... The answer is the same, even if we consider that the alien's positional notation ("$1$"s, "$b$"s, "$b^2$"s, ...) may run left-to-right. Here, direction doesn't matter, since the right-hand-side's place values are symmetric, and since on the left-hand-side we can just interchange the roles of "$\Box$" and "@". "How many fingers?" has a unique answer, regardless. Can we find variants of the puzzle that (a) aren't symmetric, yet yield the same # of fingers in each direction, (b) are "undetermined" because each direction leads to a different answer, (c) are solvable *only* in one direction?

Comment: http://www.maa.org/press/books/martin-gardner-s-mathematical-games-the-entire-collection-of-his-scientific-american-columns-on-one

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have tried to solve it more algebraically than normal people would do. (I usually do the same thing - too scientific an approach - which occasionally makes us less efficient in similar puzzles.)

**Spoilers are found below. Please stop reading if you want to solve it yourself.**

Each of the two 2-digit expressions are smaller than $b^2$, so their sum is smaller than $2b^2$. Because this is a 3-digit expression, its first digit has to be $1$. So the square is equal to 1. So we have
$$(1@) + (1@) = (1\bigstar 1)$$
Note that it ends with a $1$ - odd digit - even though the left-hand side is even - twice $(1@)$. It can only happen if the base $b$ is odd.

At any rate, the equation simplifies to 
$$2(b+@) = b^2+1 + b\bigstar$$
Moving everything non-negative to the right hand side, we have
$$ 2@ = (b-1)^2 + b \bigstar.$$
The first term is a square of an integer, i.e. $4,16,36,64,\dots $ for $b=3,5,7,9,\dots$. Note that the identity above implies that $2@$ can't be smaller than $(b-1)^2$ but $2@<2b$ and if $b\geq 5$, $2b$ is clearly smaller than $(b-1)^2$. So the only chance to find a solution is $b=3$. Then the equation simplifies to
$$ 2@ = 4+3 \bigstar .$$
The left hand side is even, so the right hand side must also be even. Therefore $\bigstar$ is either $0$ or $2$. For $\bigstar=2$ we would get $@=5$ which is too high so the only other option is $\bigstar=0$ and $@=2$ which works:
$$ (12) + (12) = (101).$$
This trinary equation is translated to decimal base as $5+5=10$. Note that those ETs have 3 fingers in total, so if they have an even number of hands, it follows that different hands have different numbers of fingers, for example 1 left finger and 2 right fingers.

Comment: I'm curious as to why this was downvoted.

Comment: Me too. I posted about ten minutes earlier, but that's hardly a reason to downvote.

Comment: Thanks for your care and implicit compliments, @JTL and @Jyrki, but I don't think it's a big issue. Let's be generous, people have the right to vote the way they want.

Comment: @barf: it was probably downvoted because there's an earlier answer that seems complete enough.

Comment: The space creatures may be using the fingers on _one_ hand for their base.  We have used number systems where there is a base 10 and a sub-base 5.  Er, a base X and a sub-base V.

Answer (score 9):

I would rather hide this behind a spoiler so that others can have fun, too. If there is a way of doing it, @-message me, please.

The only carry to the third postion that we can get in the sum of two double digit numbers is 1. Therefore `square'='1'. The sum is obviously an even number, so as the sum ends with a '1' = odd digit, the base 'b' must be an odd number. The double digit integer $x=$ 'square @' is $<2b$. Because of the carry we get that $2x\ge b^2$, so $4b>b^2$, and therefore $b<4$. The only alternative for the base is thus $b=3$. $y=$'@' must satisfy $2y>b$, because otherwise the least significant digit couldn't overflow, so '@' must be $=2$. The only remaining possibility is
$$
12_3+12_3=101_3,
$$
which checks out.

Comment: there has been a very recent discussion of spoilers on meta.

Comment: @Gerry: Thanks. I will search for more of that discussion later. I was looking for a hide/unhide button and that seems to be on the wish list, too. They have one at XKCD-fora, and it works well for cases like this, where a 'teacher' really would like to encourage others to work it out themselves, but can't stick around to discuss the problem by giving a sequence of hints as comments.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers/71396#71396 shows you how to have a gray box that text appears in when moused over.  You lead with greater than exclamation point.

Comment: The software is really not geared towards the type of questions where a hide/unhide button should be necessary. If a given person doesn't want to read an answer, they simply shouldn't scroll down.